# Rancher : Specify nodeport target

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Using Rancher 2.6+, is there a way (with annotation or something else) to specify the target FQDN of a NodePort service ?

[image]

I need to have here an external LB.

Answer (score 0):

Layer-4 load balancer (or the external load balancer) forwards traffic to Nodeports. Layer-4 load balancer allows you to forward both HTTP and TCP traffic.

Often, the underlying cloud provider supports the Layer-4 load balancer, so when you deploy RKE clusters on bare-metal servers and vSphere clusters, Layer-4 load balancer is not supported. However, a single [globally managed config-map](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/) can be used to expose services on NGINX or third-party ingress. (Source: [Rancher](https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/v2.5/how-to-guides/new-user-guides/kubernetes-resources-setup/load-balancer-and-ingress-controller/layer-4-and-layer-7-load-balancing))

Follow this [document](https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/v2.0-v2.4/getting-started/installation-and-upgrade/advanced-options/advanced-use-cases/rke-add-on/layer-4-lb) to create a target FQDN for your NodePort service. In this document they have used normal port 80 and port 443, replace them with your nodeport values. For this first you need to have your application running with NodePort configuration.